# Dynamic UITableViewCell Height for Single Table Section Only

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` with multiple sections, and I want the `UITableViewCells` in **one** of the sections to have a dynamic height based on the amount of content in a `UILabel`.

Here is my sub-classes cell called a `EntryCustomValuesCell`:

```
class EntryCustomValuesCell: UITableViewCell{
  @IBOutlet var customFieldName: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var customFieldValue: UILabel!
}
```

Here it is in my storyboard. I have set the `UILabel` (aka `customFieldValue`) on the right to have its top and bottom attach to the cell so that its height can grow dynamically.

[image: storyboard]

Here are the AutoLayout properties:

[image: autolayout]

I have set `0` lines on the `UILabel` and the dynamic height is working but with one problem: **the height of the row is fixed so the label runs over into the next section**.

See below for how this looks:

[image]

**Question:** How do I set a dynamic row height for that section based on the height of the dynamic `UILabel`?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  switch indexPath.section{
    case 0:
      //Total
      return 300
    case 1:
      //Custom Values (dynamic height)
      return ???
    default:
      return 44
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

You also need to set a constraint for the bottom of the UILabel and the bottom of the super view.

Don't forget to set the estimated row height for the table view.

Comment: Thanks! I had read about that but didn't realize I could return it as the row height.

Comment: Yeah, its not directly documented that you can do that. I found out by experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find the height of the label in the heightForRowAtIndexPath method using boundingRectWithSize.

So just load an object from your datasource

```
let myObject = myDatasource[indexPath.row]
let rect = myObject.textLabelText.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, CGFloat.max), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
return rect.height
```